# Need some hints or help in coming out the algorithm to print the following

Tags: c

How do I print this?

```
1 3 6 10 15
2 5 9 14
4 8 13
7 12
11
```

I am able to come out the following code but I am unsure on how I can combine the following to produce the result I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int start = a;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) /* This for loop produce 1 3 6 10 15 */
    {
        start = start + j;
        printf("%d ", start);
    }

    printf("\n");
    start = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) /* This for loop produce 1 2 4 7 11 */
    {
        start = start + i;
        printf("%d ", start);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please guide me as I am really not good in programming.

Comment: First step is to post compilable code (identifer `a` not found.)

Comment: You will need to nest your loops. Also, you will need more variables like `int row_start, step, row_step, current;`

Comment: Voting to reopen the question, as the OP is willing to give his/her input to the question and quite inclined towards learning the concept. No way this question is off-topic, it is very much in lines with the guidelines set by SO. Just seems like SO community failed to understand this in a bit wrong way. Hopefully they might will change their mind :-)

Comment: "How do I print **this**" This?? Would you mind explaining what that sequence **is** instead of making it a guessing game?

Comment: @KLDC: Please see, if you could get to this [doc on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fjiw82q3pgdeof/Consider%20this%20only%20for%20the%20beginning.docx?dl=0). I have tried to explain the starting point, if you able to understand this, then please let me know, I will add everythingy to it, to explain this fully. Hope you be able to learn somethingy out of it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print the mentioned pattern the fastest way is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    puts("1 3 6 10 15");
    puts("2 5 9 14");
    puts("4 8 13");
    puts("7 12");
    puts("11");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: You are not taking any input from user.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int row_start = 1, step, start_step = 2; row_step = 1, current;

    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) /* This for loop produces the rows */
    {
        current = step = row_start;
        step = start_step;

        for(int i = j; i <= 5; i++) /* This for loop produces one row */
        {
            printf("%d ", current);
            current += step;
            ++step;
        }

        printf("\n");
        row_start += row_step;
        ++row_step;
        ++start_step;
    }

    return 0;
}
```